# C# - Running / Executing "Excel to CSV File Converter" Console App from C# WinForm App

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling, console-application

I'm developing a WinForms application using C# with an OpenFileDialog, FileBrowserDialog  and I have enabled selection of multiple xls files that I want to:

1. Copy the selected files to the Consolidated directory
2. Convert the selected files to .csv files via the command prompt command [C:\CommissionRecon\ConvertExcel\ConvertExcelTo.exe ^ xxxxx.xls ^ xxxx.csv]
3. Combine all .csv files into 1 csv file using the command prompt
   [.csv File location: Copy *.csv ^ filename.csv]

What is the correct the syntax for executing this console app??

Please check the code below and recommend some fixes.  I included a lot of code so that you can get the big picture but I mainly want you to just look at the private void sourceFiles_Click method if possible.

Thanks!

Here's the code from the MainForm.CS file:

```
    // Select Source Files Button 
    private void sourceFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "i:\\CommissisionReconciliation\\Review\\";
        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;)|*.xls;*.xlsx;|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.Title = "Excel File Browser";

        DialogResult dr = this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string consolidatedFolder = targetFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath; 
            // Read the files
            foreach (String file in sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Copy each selected xlsx files into the specified TargetFolder 

                    System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, consolidatedFolder + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName)); 

                    // Convert each selected XLSX File to CSV Using the command prompt
                    // [I:\CommissisionReconciliation\App\ConvertExcel\ConvertExcelTo.exe ^ .XLS file location ^ filename.csv] 
                    // example: ConvertExcelTo.exe ^ I:\CommissisionReconciliation\ Review\_Consolidated\ALH\2011-350-00-600070-
                    // 03-09alh-AMLHS of Florida.xlsx ^ 2011-350-00-600070-03-09alh-AMLHS of Florida.csv

                    Process covertFilesProcess = new Process();

                    covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "I:\\CommissisionReconciliation\\App\\ConvertExcel\\";
                    covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName; 
                    covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "ConvertExcelTo.exe" + " ^ " + targetFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + "^" + sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName + ".csv";
                    covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    covertFilesProcess.Start();

                    StreamReader sOut = covertFilesProcess.StandardOutput;
                    StreamReader sErr = covertFilesProcess.StandardError;

                }

                catch (SecurityException ex)
                {
                    // The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc.
                    MessageBox.Show("Security error. The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc. Please contact your administrator for details.\n\n" +
                    "Error message: " + ex.Message + "\n\n" +);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Could not load the image - probably related to Windows file system permissions.
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot display the image: " + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\'))
                     + ". You may not have permission to read the file, or " +
                     "it may be corrupt.\n\nReported error: " + ex.Message);
                }

                finally
                {
                    sOut.Close();
                    sErr.Close();
                }

                try
                {
                    // Combine all .csv files into 1 csv file using the command prompt
                    // [.csv File location: Copy *.csv ^ filename.csv]
                    // example: [.CSV I:\CommissisionReconciliation\ Review\_Consolidated\ALH\: Copy *.csv 
                    // ^2011-350-00-600070-03-09alh-AMLHS of Florida.csv)

                    Process consolidateFilesProcess = new Process();

                    // substring function to take off the extension from sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName
                    // int csvFileName.Length = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName.Length - 3;  

                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "I:\\CommissisionReconciliation\\App\\ConvertExcel\\";
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName; 
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = ".CSV " + " ^ " + targetFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + ": Copy *.csv ^" + csvFileName+ ".csv";
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    consolidateFilesProcess.Start();

                    StreamReader sOut = consolidateFilesProcess.StandardOutput;
                    StreamReader sErr = consolidateFilesProcess.StandardError;
                }

                catch (SecurityException ex)
                {
                    // The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc.
                    MessageBox.Show("Security error. The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc. Please contact your administrator for details.\n\n" +
                    "Error message: " + ex.Message + "\n\n" +);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Could not load the image - probably related to Windows file system permissions.
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot display the image: " + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\'))
                     + ". You may not have permission to read the file, or " +
                     "it may be corrupt.\n\nReported error: " + ex.Message);
                }

                finally
                {
                    sOut.Close();
                    sErr.Close();
                }

            } // ends foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        }  // ends if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    } // ends selectFilesButton_Click method 

        if (sourceFileOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        textBoxSourceFiles.Text = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileNames;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        if (sourceFileOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Log("Source Files: " + sourceFileOpenFileDialog.SelectedFiles);
        }
        textBoxSourceFiles.Text = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.SelectedFiles;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using `// ends foreach (...)` you should refactor these blocks of code into separate methods so `foreach` fits on single screen.

Comment: @gaearon, sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you provide an example?

Comment: At the ending braces you put comments that specify which was the opening brace (e.g. `// ends if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)`). This is a bad style because it shows that your code blocks are long enough so they don't fit on the screen. Such code is hard to read and maintain. Often code would look better if you extracted parts of it into separate methods. For instance, you could create a `StartConverter` method and call it in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the ProcessSTartInfo, you need to specify the executeable of the process you want to run as filename!

For example:

```
Process covertFilesProcess = new Process();

covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "I:\\CommissisionReconciliation\\App\\ConvertExcel\\";
covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ConvertExcelTo.exe";
covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "^ " + targetFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + "^" + sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName + ".csv";
covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
covertFilesProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
covertFilesProcess.Start();

StreamReader sOut = covertFilesProcess.StandardOutput;
StreamReader sErr = covertFilesProcess.StandardError;
```

Comment: thanks for your response! I'll try that! What using directives or assembly references should I add to prevent these errors??
'fileName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
'Process' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
'SecurityException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
'sOut' does not exist in the current context
'sErr' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Frank Hale, thanks for your response. What did you edit in the code on here? Do you have anything to add on how to fix my errors?

Comment: What about string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath); ?

Answer (score 1):

Well first thing:

```
try
{
    ...
    StreamReader sOut = covertFilesProcess.StandardOutput;
}
sOut.close();
```

sOut is declared inside the try block - it's not visible outside. You need to move it to the outside lke this

```
StreamReader sOut = null;
try
{
    ...
    sOut = covertFilesProcess.StandardOutput;
}

if (sOut != null) sOut.Close();
```

Same with sErr

**Update**: for SecurityException you need to add using System.Security and for Process you need to add using System.Diagnostics. And the variable fileName is not declared - so the compiler doesn't know what it is.

Comment: thanks for your response. Under the code you gave me, What should I put instead of the "..." under: "StreamReader sOut = null; 
try
{
    ...
    sOut = ...
}" ??

Comment: I have already declared the sOut & sErr Variables in the code above as follows: "StreamReader sOut = covertFilesProcess.StandardOutput;
                        StreamReader sErr = covertFilesProcess.StandardError;" Is that what you mean with the ... and sOut=... ?

Comment: With `sOut = ...` I wanted to indicate the assignment like `sOut = covertFilesProcess.StandardOutput`. I updated the answer.